# Applicable Group Problem Involving Modular Arithmetic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic

Question: Show that $(5, 15, 25, 35)$ is a group under multiplication modulo 40.

So I first decided to make a Cayley Table that looks like this:

[image]

I apologize that I do not know how to make a Cayley Table in MathJax.

So I know it is closed, and associative because of multiplication inheritance.

I am just confused about the identity element. I could use some descriptive advice about how you find it. I know once you find that, you can use the table to find inverses of each.

Comment: Well, what is the identity element by definition?

Comment: I know the identity element of multiplication is just $1$, right?

Comment: The identity element of a group is an element $e$ so that $e \cdot x =  x \cdot e = x$ for all $x$ in our group. So is there an element in $(5, 15, 25, 35)$ that when you multiply it by the other elements acts like the identity after you reduce mod $40$?

Comment: Ah, interesting. It just clicked! Thank you guys. Sorry, all this stuff is trivial, but new and somewhat challenging to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [{5,15,25,35} is a group under multiplication mod 40](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/693670/5-15-25-35-is-a-group-under-multiplication-mod-40)

Answer (score 2):

Your identity element is $25$ because  in mod $40$ you have

$$ 25\times 5=125 \equiv 5$$

$$ 25\times 15=375\equiv 15$$

$$25\times 25=625\equiv 25$$
$$25\times 35=875\equiv 35$$

It is interesting to see that for  this group every element is its own inverse.

Answer (score 1):

From the Cayley table we recognize the identity element ($25$, in red) because of the identities of the underlying set $\{5,15,25,35\}$ in the line and column labelled by it (in blue):
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\times_{40} & 5 & 15 & \color{red}{25} & 35\\
\hline
5 & 25 & 35 & \color{blue}{5} & 15\\
15 & 35 & 25 & \color{blue}{15} & 5\\
\color{red}{25} & \color{blue}{5} & \color{blue}{15} & \color{blue}{25} & \color{blue}{35}\\
35 & 15 & 5 & \color{blue}{35} & 25\\
\end{array}

Associativity is well known to be verified since the operation is a restriction to a closed subset of $\mathbb{Z}_{40}$ of an operation which is associative on $\mathbb{Z}_{40}$.

#### But now hold on a moment.

$\mathbb{Z}_{40}$ **is not a group under multiplication**, it is only a (commutative) monoid. So - this is very important - claiming that $\{5,15,25,35\}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{Z}_{40}$ under multiplication **does not imply that it is a group**. It is a sub-semigroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{40}$ hence it is a commutative semigroup; it has identity element (not even the same as $\mathbb{Z}_{40}$) hence it is a commutative monoid. You had only proved that your structure is a commutative monoid, not a group.

How to prove that it is a group?

You had missed to say that all the lines and columns of our Cayley table are bijections of $\{5,15,25,35\}$, so that is the Cayley table of a quasigroup too. This wasn't trivial: not even $\mathbb{Z}_n\backslash\{0\}$ is a group under multiplication (and the lines and columns of its Cayley table are in general not bijections of $\mathbb{Z}_n\backslash\{0\}$) if $n$ isn't prime, and $40$ isn't prime.

Only now, a structure which is a commutative monoid **and** a quasigroup is a commutative (or *Abelian*) group.

Finally, the property *"every element is its own inverse"* stated in the answer by Mohammad may be reworded saying that the structure is *unipotent* (all the elements of the diagonal of the Cayley table are equals to the identity element).

So, our finite group of order $4$ is an unipotent Abelian group.

See also [this other answer to a very similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3618270/142842).